# image library software for a company

Tags: images, organizer-software

Can anyone recommend a great tool for managing photos across a company?

Ideally we'd like to be able to tag photos, but the idea is that anyone in the company should be able to use the application or whatever to search for images in the library.

I've tried picasa and windows live photo gallery, but ideally i'd like it on a server or something so that people can search from their own PC's

Thanks

Comment: can you please give a budget estimate?

Comment: @FlorenzKley shopping requests are explicitly off-topic on SU.

Comment: Its not shopping request (I suppose) but question about specific, specialistic tool - why to close that?

Answer (score 2):

The best sollution as far as I know is Fotoware - Index Manager + Fotostation. Lots of companies with indexes of 500k+ of imags uses it.

It can search in 500k+ database of images in few seconds. I dont remember licensing restrictions but I'm sure that Your local resseler can help You.

Basically You need a "Index Manager" installed on server and then Fotostation on Worksations.

http://www.fotoware.com/

Answer (score 0):

Phase One Media Pro (what used to be iView Media Pro and later Microsoft Expression Media). Multi-user environment supported as "shared catalog". Maybe overkill if all you want is "shared tagging".

One downside: they really want you to use Capture One.

http://www.phaseone.com/Software/Media-Pro/Features.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Numerous installers, cloud services, VM images and stacks are available at [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/) and [TurnKey](http://turnkeylinux.org).

MediaWiki is one by Wikipedia (images at BitNami and TKL).

[Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/) and Gallery are two designed specifically for photos and only photos (images at BitNami and TKL); EC2 and VirtualBox-compatible stacks for installation on 3+ platforms. I think TKL has ISOs for appliances as well.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I found:

- [Canto Cumulus](http://www.canto.com/en/products/whats-new.php?PHPSESSID=fef8c081e7ee597063a54c52b6bcb4f0)
- [ImageFolio](http://imagefolio.com/)
- [Extensis Portfolio](http://www.extensis.com/en/products/portfolio8-5/overview.jsp)

Comment: if we used a shared folder and one person started tagging pictures would that be reflected for other users?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I don't see why not.  You can set read/write permissions for a workgroup : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone

Comment: Shared foler = very bad idea. No tags, terrible slow operations, slow search, miniatures - forget about it...

Comment: You're right, I'll edit that part out